# Hive : Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am working on a project wehere I have used hive database for storing data locally. it works fine initally. but when I close the app remove it from background apps and then re-open it throws the error and app crrashes..
`Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

I don't understand why this error is occuring.

here my code.

```
...

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  Hive.registerAdapter<ScheduleModel>(ScheduleModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<AddressModel>(AddressModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<ProductModel>(ProductModelAdapter());

  await Hive.initFlutter(); // Initialize Hive

  await Future.wait([
    Hive.openBox<ProductModel>('products'),
    Hive.openBox<ScheduleModel>('schedule'),
    Hive.openBox<AddressModel>('address'),
  ]);

// Check if the boxes are already open before opening them
  if (!Hive.isBoxOpen('products')) {
    await Hive.openBox<ProductModel>('products');
  }
  if (!Hive.isBoxOpen('schedule')) {
    await Hive.openBox<ScheduleModel>('schedule');
  }
  if (!Hive.isBoxOpen('address')) {
    await Hive.openBox<AddressModel>('address');
  }
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  String? fcmToken = await messaging.getToken();
  await messaging.subscribeToTopic('DailyOrder');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setString("fcmToken", fcmToken.toString());

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
...//main function
```

address model

```
@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class AddressModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String addtype;
  @HiveField(1)
  String houseno;
  @HiveField(2)
  String buildingname;
  @HiveField(3)
  String area;
  @HiveField(4)
  String landmark;
  @HiveField(5)
  String city;
  @HiveField(6)
  String state;
  @HiveField(7)
  String latitude; // Add this field
  @HiveField(8)
  String longitude; // Add this field

  AddressModel({
    required this.addtype,
    required this.houseno,
    required this.buildingname,
    required this.area,
    required this.landmark,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.latitude, // Initialize latitude
    required this.longitude, // Initialize longitude
  });
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
anchor = null
E/flutter (26229): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
E/flutter (26229): #0      _FirstPageState._getAddressFromLatLng.<anonymous closure> (package:newmart/OTP/landing_page.dart:154:18)
E/flutter (26229): #1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1661:54)
```

code from 132 - 160

```
// Latitude: 37.4219983, Longitude: -122.084
  Future<void> _getAddressFromLatLng(Position position) async {
    await placemarkFromCoordinates(
            _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude)
        .then((List<Placemark> placemarks) async {
      Placemark place = placemarks[0];
      city = place.locality.toString();
      statename = place.administrativeArea.toString();
      pincode = place.postalCode.toString();
      area = place.subLocality.toString();
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString("city", place.locality.toString());
      prefs.setString("pincode", place.postalCode.toString());
      prefs.setString("area", place.subLocality.toString());
      prefs.setString("statename", place.administrativeArea.toString());
      prefs.setString("country", place.country.toString());
      setState(() {
        // print(place.toString());
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you please share code of where error is occuring

Comment: @HitarthChhunchha
Sir, It works fine in debug mode but when I run the app in release mode in vs code it gives me that error in debug console I have updated my question. and it happen when I add products to hive db and close the next time i open it does not open.

Comment: share minimal code of landing_page.dart around line 154 would be better to understand your problem

Comment: Hello sir, I''ve added code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check somewhere you need to provide string but there is null, just log the values to check which one is giving null and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Sir, It works fine in debug mode but when I run the app in release mode in vs code it gives me that error in debug console I have updated my question. and it happen when I add products to hive db and close the next time i open it does not open.